# What license can embed a Power BI report to a public web (html file)

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Hi I am using a free license of Power BI account to build report. If I want to embed the Power BI report to my company's html page, should I have to own a Pro license to do that?

Basically I am asking after my couple of days of free trial license, can I still have the function to do so?
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the free version you can use 'Publish to Web', but reports have to be in 'My Workspace' you'll not be able to share items to web from other workspaces, that will require a Pro license. If the option is turned off in the Power BI tenant, (it is turned off by default) by your Power BI Admin, then you will not be able to publish items at all.

More details on the MS Doc website here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-features

Please note, publish to web should only be used for data that can be consumed by anyone freely as it is not secure. You haven't mentioned what type of report it is, or the data it will contain in your company's html page. If it contains company confidential data, do not use 'publish to web' as anyone with the url can access the report.

If for example, it shows freely available data, then it is safe to use. Some local authorities use 'Publish to Web' to show data such as bin collection, service KPI's, covid rates, and pollution levels in the city center, all publicly accessible data, presented in a visual manner.

If the data cannot be shared publicly, then your other option is to only share with other Pro users to allow show the page in your website, it will then prompt the user to login Power BI.

Comment: Hi Jon, the data is for public use, just need a better way to show to the public. In that case, I won't need to buy a pro license. thanks for the answer